# Magento: How to write web service api for widget?

Tags: web-services, magento, widget

I have written some widgets like best seller etc in magento and now I want to create web service APIs for those widgets but I can't find anything online related to that. Is it even possible and if not then why not?
Any link or answer would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: why look to the web when you can look to Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2 and see what classes it extends/inherits and you get your answer

Comment: I looked into that but there is nothing of widgets in that, as its name says it only work class wise like product.